# Insert or update on table "vehicle" violates foreign key constraint,vehicle has many to one relation with user table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables User and vehicle.

- user has one to many relation with vehicle and
- vehicle has many to one relation with user.

First time adding user and vehicle is working good. When i try to add new vehicle to existing user getting exception

> ```
> ERROR: insert or update on table "vehicle" violates foreign key constraint "fk2q70uto2vl2oh4enr071s58yb"
>   Detail: Key (vehicleid)=(4) is not present in table "usertraveldo".
> UserDO
> ```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usertraveldo")
public class UserTravelDO implements Serializable {
@GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
@Id
private int id; 
private String username;
private String password;
private String hint;
private String firstname;
private String middlename;
private String lastname;
private Boolean status;

@JoinColumn(name="addressid")
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private AddressTravelDO address;

@JoinColumn(name="roleid")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private RoleMasterDO role;

@Column (name = "vehicleid",updatable=false, insertable=false)
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name="vehicleid")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
private List<VehicleTravelDO> vehicle = new ArrayList<VehicleTravelDO>();
}
```

VehicleDO

```
@Entity
@Table(name="vehicle")
public class VehicleTravelDO implements Serializable {


@GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
@Id
//@Column (name = "vehicleid")
private int vehicleid;
private String vehicletype;
private String vehiclenumber;
private int totalseats;
private int availableseats;
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name="id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
private UserTravelDO user;
}
```

Exception

```
Hibernate: insert into vehicle (availableseats, totalseats, id, vehiclenumber, vehicletype, vehicleid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2016-12-09 12:58:59.742  WARN 5872 --- [nio-9001-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
2016-12-09 12:58:59.743 ERROR 5872 --- [nio-9001-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: insert or update on table "vehicle" violates foreign key constraint "fk2q70uto2vl2oh4enr071s58yb"
Detail: Key (vehicleid)=(4) is not present in table "usertraveldo".
2016-12-09 12:58:59.743  INFO 5872 --- [nio-9001-exec-6] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2016-12-09 12:58:59.743 ERROR 5872 --- [nio-9001-exec-6] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [could not execute statement]
2016-12-09 12:58:59.751  WARN 5872 --- [nio-9001-exec-6] o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Application {}TravelServiceImpl has thrown exception, unwinding now
```

Service code

```
   public Response addVehicle(VehicleTravelBo vehicle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UserTravelDO userDO = new UserTravelDO();
    Session session =         travelHibernateDao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    /*Query query = session.createQuery(HQL_LOAD_ALL_USER_ID);
    query.setParameter("id", vehicle.getUserid());
    userDO = (UserTravelDO) query.uniqueResult();*/

    userDO = session.get(UserTravelDO.class, vehicle.getUserid());
    if(userDO == null)
    {
        System.out.println("notexist");
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println(userDO.getId());
    VehicleTravelDO vehicleDO = ProfileDtoConverter.convertBOtoDO(vehicle);
    vehicleDO.setUser(userDO);
    session.save(vehicleDO);
    }
    HashMap praf= new HashMap();
    praf.put("message", "user  updated");
    //System.out.println("Leavetable updated successfully");
    return Response.ok(praf).build();

}
```

From two days i am fighting with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all**, you should work within transaction.

```
public Response addVehicle(VehicleTravelBo vehicle) {
Session session = travelHibernateDao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.getTransaction().begin();


UserTravelDO userDO = session.get(UserTravelDO.class, vehicle.getUserid());
if(userDO == null)
{
    System.out.println("notexist");
}
else
{
   System.out.println(userDO.getId());
   VehicleTravelDO vehicleDO = ProfileDtoConverter.convertBOtoDO(vehicle);
   userDO.addVehicle(vehicleDO);
}

session.getTransaction().commit();
HashMap praf= new HashMap();
praf.put("message", "user  updated");
//System.out.println("Leavetable updated successfully");
return Response.ok(praf).build();
```

}

**Second**. Your `class UserTravelDO` should has the following method

```
public void addVehicle(VehicleTravelDO vehicleTravelDO){
    vehicleTravelDO.setUser(this);
    vehicle.add(vehicleTravelDO);
}
```

When you works within tx, Hibernate does *dirty checking*, so when you'll add new vehicle it will detect it, and then performs corresponding call(probably on tx commit).

**Third**. Don't use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on your `private UserTravelDO user;` field. Let's consider you want to remove single vehicle; then appropriate user should be also removed, because of cascade.

**Fourth**. Your mapping is not correct.
In your  `class UserTravelDO` use

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<VehicleTravelDO> vehicle = new ArrayList<VehicleTravelDO>();
```

Also change `class VehicleTraverDO`. Use the following mapping

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private UserTravelDO user;
```

**Please be clear with your associations**. If you have oneToMany (like many `VehicleTravelDO` associate with one `UserTravelDO`, than you should have column `user_id` in `vehicle` table, that represents foreign key to `user`.

So now, you should have `user_id` column in your vehicle table, that is foreign key to user table.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Same error is coming even after changing the code as you suggested @Taras

Comment: In my project there is bidirectional mapping means user has one to one relation with vehicle and vehicle has many to one relation with user, when I try to add multiple vehicle to existing user then I am getting "ERROR: insert or update on table "vehicle" violates foreign key constraint "fk2q70uto2vl2oh4enr071s58yb" Detail: Key (vehicleid)=(4) is not present in table "usertraveldo".vehicleid)=(4) is not present in table usertraveldo",where vehicle with id 4 is new one want to add, why its asking me that it should present at user table side.

Comment: Your bidirectional association is **OneToMany** and **ManyToOne**. You're very wrong saying  that _ user has one to one relation with vehicle and vehicle has many to one relation with user_

Comment: You asked "why its asking me that it should present at user table side?" Because your mapping is wrong. Your table vehicle should contain foreign key to user table. What is  name of the column, that represents foreign key?

Comment: Ya vehicle table contains userid as a foreign key .

Comment: I've changed the answer, please follow all 4 steps. Then you will be able to add multiple vehicle to your user without errors.

Comment: Your welcome. It should work, anyway please be clear changing your mapping.

Comment: I have one question .in fourth step you mentioned mappedBy = "user" ,here user is table name of user entity right?

Comment: No, user is field name in your VehicleTravelDO class @manjugkk

Comment: You use mappedBy, because you have already map this association in class VehicleTraveDO. So you just point name of the field on the other side of association.

Comment: @Tars Its worked for me ...Thank you very much...And thank you for your explanation and your patience....